# Sending parameters to usemutation and always get an error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Im trying to send two parameters name and description but i always get
Error: Variable "$name" of required type "String!" was not provided.
Variable "$description" of required type "String!" was not provided.

what im missing

```
const ADD_CATEGORY = gql`
 mutation addCategory($name: String!, $description: String!) {
  addCategory(name: $name, description: $description) {
   id
   name
  }
 }
`;
```

hooks

```
  const [addCategory] = useMutation(ADD_CATEGORY);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
```

function

```
const createCategory = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addCategory({ variables: { name, description } });
};
```

Even if i pass variables directly

```
addCategory({ variables: { name:"nombre", description:"descripcion" } });
```

Request Payload

```
operationName: "AddCategory"
query: "mutation AddCategory($name: String!, $description: String!) {↵  
addCategory(name: $name, description: $description) {↵    id↵    name↵ __typename↵  }↵}↵"
variables: {name: "category", description: "a new description"}
```

request on graphQl chrome extension, it working

```
mutation {
 addCategory(name: "info", description: "description") {
  id
  name
  }
}
```

My dependencies

```
 "@apollo/client": "^3.2.7",
 "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
```

Comment: test in playground/extension using "query variables" - compare the same query

Comment: i test find category by id and it said "message": "Variable \"$id\" of required type \"Int!\" was not provided.", when i use query variables, without this, it works

Comment: ... different use case? ... no 'id' variable passed? ... doesn't matter ... you need to learn how to work with variables, query variables